# Set default button inside div - but I don't know ID / class

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, defaultbutton

I have a page where user controls are loaded dynamically into a div/panel. I don't know anything about the content of these user controls, besides they have a button.

When the user is inside this div / panel (using the user control), I want the button inside the div/panel, to be the default button.
Right now, my sidewide search button is the default button no matter what.

I can't add "defaultButton=mybutton" in the user controls, and I can't add a class to the buttons.

How do I solve the problem?

Thanks :)

Comment: Seems you dont know anything and wants everything :)

Comment: I don't completely understand what you are trying to do. If you just want to select a button, why don't you just use `$('wrapper_div').find('button')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
 $("#CalculatorDiv").keypress(function (e) {
                if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
                    var div = $("#CalculatorDiv");
                    var firstInput = div.find("input[type=submit]");
                    firstInput.click();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

:-) So a combination of find and keypress event.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific. Better yet, post the code.

By default button, do you mean pressing "Return" will make the button submit? In that case, you can enclose it in a form.

To access the button, you can do that via javascript's document.getElementById

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById

You can also use jQuery to access the element by class, type or nearest button element to the div tag. Maybe use the "find" method in jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain how you are accomplishing this based upon your description but what you could do is set the `Control.ID` and then you can use `FindControl` to locate the UserControl.

```
UserControl uc = (UserControl)PANELID.FindControl(Control.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but can't you search for `<input type="button" .../>` and than add the default code part to it?

---

EDIT: read your question wrong, asumed it was a webpage 'cuz of the 'div'.
Normally in C#, you can select the Controls inside a panel and then search on the type to find the button

Comment: In all fairness, this question is tagged both `html` and `jquery`. It's only sane to assume that a question about buttons and divs with both of those tags is referring to a webpage... especially for those of us who don't know `C#`.

Comment: It's tagged C# too. This is why I didn't remove the wrong code, I just added a C# hint

Answer (score -1):

```
$("your div").children().blur(function(){
$(#button).focus();
});
```